# Handle Loading status useMutation

Tags: reactjs

I use useMutation and send multiple requests. Have both request success and failure. But when have a request failure in the last, the status will change to error and I don't want that to happend.
How can I handle state always isLoading until all request done or how to know when all request done

```
const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation(addMultiple, {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
           console.log(data)
        },
        onError: (err) => {
           console.log(err)
        },

    });
```

Comment: Where does `useMutation` come from?

Comment: From React Query

Comment: Hoe does `addMultiple` look like? It should return a Promise that resolves when all requests are done.

Comment: yes, how can i do that?